# php list of filenames with special characters output to xml

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

Alert: I am extremely inexperienced with php.

I'm trying to read the names of a list of files on the server and create an XML file with these. Some of these have foreign language characters and this causes problems during XML creation.

After searching around I realise I probably need to use `htmlspecialchars` or `rawurlencode`, but I have been unable to get these working.

The code below was constructed from code I found online. There is no particular reason for doing anything this way other than not knowing any better.

```
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

header("Content-Type: text/xml;");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><list>';
foreach($objects as $name){

    echo '<file><loc>'.$name.fileName.'</loc><lastmod>'.date('Y-m-d',filemtime($name)).'</lastmod></file>';
}
echo '</list>';
```

**Clarification**: It's not that `rawurlencode` fails, it's just that I don't know how to save it in the XML file decoded

```
<file>
    <loc>
        http://%2Fhome%2Fusers%2Fjdfvnftp%2Fjdfv.nl%2Fptp%2Ftorrents%2FBuck.2011.DVD.XviD.AVI.106682.torrent.importedfileName
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2012-05-29</lastmod>
</file>
```

Comment: u can also try with utf8_encode() and see if that helps. Note: you would need to do this to try it:  echo '<file><loc>'.utf8_encode($name.fileName).'</loc><lastmod>'.date('Y-m-d',filemtime($name)).'</lastmod></file>';

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: apparently this can also have to do with your filesystem check this discussion and a number of tests they have you can run to narrow down your problem: http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/filesystem-encoding-and-php

Comment: be sure to have your XML with harmless html entities;              $str = str_replace(array("&",">","<","'",'"'),array("&amp;","&gt;","&lt;","&apos;","&quot;"),$raw);